# Vue + Vuetify V2 not working on older iOS versions

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

After Upgrading to Vuetify 2 users report, that the website (https://lernzettel.org/#/) is not working on for instance the IPhone 5 (running the newest available version of iOS) - quite a bummer.

Vuetify 2.0.11
Vue 2.6.10
Standard Cli Config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to polyfill your Vuetify app to support Safari 9 on iOS 10
From the Vuetify GitHub [README](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify#browser-support)

#### Browser Support

Vuetify supports all modern browsers, including IE11 and Safari 9+ (using polyfills).
From mobile to laptop computer to desktop, you can rest assured that your application will work as expected.

Interested in the bleeding edge? Try the Vue CLI 3 Webpack SSR (Server side rendered) template and build websites optimized for SEO.

For more information about IE11 and Safari 9+ polyfills, visit our [Quick Start Guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#ie11-safari-9-support)